# Ways to distribute 15 distinct kinds of toys with at least 10 of each kind to 10 kids so that each kid gets at most one kind of each toy?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm struggling to understand how to approach this question to begin with. I think there are a total of 150 toys (since there are 10 of each of the 15 kinds of toys) but otherwise I don't know where to start from here. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are $\geq 150$ toys, you have to distribute toys such that no child gets $\geq 2$ toys of one kind

Comment: My 2 cents (I'm a beginner)... Can a kid get only one toy? Or do you distribute as many of the $150$ plus possible in a way where each kid gets at most one kind... then wouldn't that mean that each kid could get a complete set of all $15$? Then to figure out how to distribute the $150$ plus toys I feel like you'd need to know how many of each kind, not that there are just at least $10$ of each.

Comment: I suspect that the question should be worded as follows:  Ways to distribute $15$ distinct kinds of toys with at least $10$ of each kind so that each kid gets at most one of each kind of toy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that the children are distinguishable - so giving toy A to Alice and toy B to Bob is a different distribution from giving toy B to Alice and toy A to Bob. However, I am going to assume that two toys of the same kind are *not* distinguishable.

I am also going to assume that there is no lower limit on the number of toys each child has i.e. some children may have no toys.

To have no more than one of each kind of toy, each child must have some subset of the 15 kinds of toys. There are $2^{15}$ different subsets if having no toys is a valid outcome. If every child has a toy of every kind then 10 toys of each kind are required - but we know there are at least 10 toys of each kind, so this is a valid distribution.

Assuming the children are distinguishable and there is no lower limit on the number of toys each child has, then the total number of distributions is $(2^{15})^{10} = 2^{150}$.